# ZedGraph curve with multiple segments

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to draw a curve which consists of multiple segments? For example, I have 4 points and I need to plot curve with segments from *point1* to *point2* and from *point3* to *point4*, with no connection between *point2* and *point3*. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is to plot two different curves.

1) Create two `ZedGraph.PointPairList` items, one with Point1 and Point2 and the other with Point3 and Point4.

2) Use `ZedGraph.GraphPane.AddCurve` to add two curves, using the overloaded method that takes a PointPairList/iPointList.

Comment: Thanks. I also considered this approach, but thought that exists more sophisticated way to do this, which allows to avoid hiding legend for each of the curve.